# read.csv warning 'EOF within quoted string' to read whole file

Tags: r, csv, eof, read.table, read.csv

I have a .csv file that contains 285000 observations. Once I tried to import dataset, here is the warning and it shows 166000 observations.

```
Joint <- read.csv("joint.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string

When I coded with quote, as follows:

```
Joint2 <- read.csv("joint.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote="", fill= TRUE)
```

Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names

When I coded like that, it shows 483000 observations:

```
Joint <- read.table("joint.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote="", fill= TRUE)
```

What should I do to read the file properly?

Comment: Can you post a small excerpt of your CSV file? It is hard to help you without see the format of your data.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem has to do with file encoding. There are a lot of special characters in the header.
If you know how your file is encoded you can specify using the `fileEncoding` argument to `read.csv`.

Otherwise you could try to use `fread` from [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html). It is able to read the file despite the encoding issues. It will also be significantly faster for reading such a large data file.

Comment: Here is the description when I used fread(): Expecting 62 cols, but line 46 contains text after processing all cols. Try again with fill=TRUE. Another reason could be that fread's logic in distinguishing one or more fields having embedded sep=',' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes has failed. If quote='' doesn't help, please file an issue to figure out if the logic could be improved.                                                                         
Joint <- fread("joint.csv", sep="auto", na.strings = c("NA","N/A",""),fill = TRUE, quote='')

Comment: It works for me just using `fread("file.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")`. The file might have been changed when uploaded to Google Docs. Can you share it somewhere else where we can be sure the file is unchanged?

Comment: One problem is, that some quoted strings contain unescaped quotes. For instance in the column `Poz No 2` on line 68 there is a string: `"SCH160 - FITTING, OLET FLG  MSS SP-97/  B16.5 6" (150 MM) LG RF CL 600 A350-LF2 CL1"`. `read.table` and `fread` are not able to determine that the quotation mark in the middle (`6" (150 MM)`) is not supposed to terminate the string. You will need to escape such quotes with backslash to fix this.